# ORA-01017 : How do I create a New User in Oracle SQL Developer [ SOLVED ]

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to connect with a new user that I recently made but when I try to making a new connection this error appears

[image: ORA-01017]

I acces to the database  , scroll down to Other users , right click and click on Create  user.
And I'm sure of that user exist and I'm writing the username and the password correctly.

Comment: There could be many issues. How did you create the user? what database did you create the user in etc... Your example doesn't provide enough information to provide a meaningful answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all ! I found the  mistake.

I was connecting to the Database by this way  :

[image]

[image: login]

And when I was in that session making the New User, the user was not being created because I was doing it without SYSDBA Role. After, I was trying to login with the user I was just "created", but since I had not created it with S**YSDBA Role**, the system threw me the error **ORA-01017**.

When I realized that , I right clicked the **DataBase** and I checked the **Properties**.

[image]

And effectively  I was login in  without the **SYSDBA Role** ,  so I fix that , I enter the username , password and the **SYSDBA Role**.

[image]

After that , I connected to the **Database** with the Role **SYSDBA** user. I created the **New User** I was trying to making and finally it worked when I log in with it !!!

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough info, but one of the many possibilities is that your PATH variable is broken. Or you have old connection files that even with the right user/pass they point to the wrong server,service,name. Try to download new instant clients. I will give you some examples:

- instant client basic lite win64 12.1.0.2.0
- instant client sqlplus win64 12.1.0.2.0

A fact about the Sql developer OS authentication is that Sql developer always tries to authorize by substituting to the user name `\` without domain name.

Comment: Luckily SQL Developer doesn't need Instant Client.  Also if you wanted to run Instant Client sqlplus you wouldn't need the jdbc package.